Update environment variable based on response body in .http file (vscode and rest-client)
I want to override the local.token value in settings.json.
I can read the body and update a local variable but this means I need to run the token request and manually update the environment variable for every other request.
### Token Request
# @name postLogin
POST {{baseUrlWithouAPI}}/connect/token
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "userName": "username",
  "password": "password"
}

### set the token in the file variable called tokenLocal
@tokenLocal = {{postLogin.response.body.accessToken}} # this works
{{token}} = {{postLogin.response.body.accessToken}} # this does not work

Expected to update the env variable with the following syntax
{{token}} = {{postLogin.response.body.accessToken}} # this does not work
or
@@token = {{postLogin.response.body.accessToken}} # this does not work

